# Relationship between two words part of the same sentence

Tags: computational-linguistics

I'm looking for some help on strategy to be used for finding out if word is spoken in relation to another word.

For ex: The pool is dirty.
Here dirty is spoken w.r.t pool

However,
The pool was great but bathroom was dirty.
Here dirty is spoken w.r.t bathroom and not pool.

What linguistic strategies can be used to enable this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking for a way to link a subject to a predicate. (Informally, an adjective is a "predicate" when it "acts like a verb": *red* in *the red book* isn't a predicate, but in *the book is red* it is.)

The standard way to find relationships like this is "dependency parsing", which basically means "figuring out the syntactic relationships between words". In this case, I think [the Stanford CoreNLP dependency parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) will do what you want.

Here's a visualization of what the Stanford parser can tell you, which will probably help more than a paragraph of text (made [here](http://corenlp.run/)):

[image]

(This is just a visualization: the parser actually returns everything as a flat data structure, which your program can then use as it likes.)

If you go with this parser, you'll want to look for words with the `JJ` tag (adjectives), with an `nsubj` (noun subject) relationship to an `NN` (noun). If you're also interested in *attributive* adjectives, look for a `NN` with an `amod` (adjective modifier) relationship to a `JJ`.